# Queue Simulation in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, queue, simulation

I'm trying to create a simulation of queue system in bank using Python as my mini project. The program is about to divide the right amount of queue length for each teller so that there is no one teller that get a longer queue than other tellers.

Here's my code so far:

```
`queue_dict = {'Angel':[],
          'Mellysa':[],
          'David':[],
          'Thom':[],
          'Monica':[]
          }

queue_no = 0
queue_no +=1
customer_name = input("Enter your name: ")
if customer_name == " ":
    break

# Find the teller that has lowest number of queue
lowest_queue = np.inf
for teller_name, customers_queue in queue_dict.items():
    if len(customers_queue) < lowest_queue:
        lowest_queue = len(customers_queue)
        chosen_teller = teller_name

# Get the customer on the queue of the chosen teller
queue_dict[chosen_teller].append(customer_name)

print(f"{customer_name}, please go to teller {chosen_teller}")
print()`
```

My question is, from my code above, can someone tell me how to generate a code if I want to get my first and last customer?

Comment: Your code should first have logic to serve a customer, removing that customer from the relevant queue. Otherwise this question has a trivial answer: just keep track of the first and last customer that was input.

Comment: Also, on this site *"how to generate a code"* is not a suitable question. You are expected to try to implement what you want to achieve and ask about the problem you encountered, showing your code and explaining where it goes wrong, and what the expected behaviour should have been.